# What is the purpose of Serial.println() without an argument?

Tags: serial, arduino-mega

I am attempting to control a stepper motor with [Sparkfun's Big Easy Driver](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/big-easy-driver-hookup-guide?_ga=2.180625124.2131528762.1552592364-1334954616.1545061294), and I see the line "Serial.println();" they put in the example code. Why is there no argument and what function does this serve?

```
//Declare pin functions on Arduino
#define stp 2
#define dir 3
#define MS1 4
#define MS2 5
#define MS3 6
#define EN  7

//Declare variables for functions
char user_input;
int x;
int y;
int state;

void setup() {
  pinMode(stp, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dir, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MS1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MS2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MS3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(EN, OUTPUT);
  resetBEDPins(); //Set step, direction, microstep and enable pins to default states
  Serial.begin(9600); //Open Serial connection for debugging
  Serial.println("Begin motor control");
  Serial.println();
  //Print function list for user selection
  Serial.println("Enter number for control option:");
  Serial.println("1. Turn at default microstep mode.");
  Serial.println("2. Reverse direction at default microstep mode.");
  Serial.println("3. Turn at 1/16th microstep mode.");
  Serial.println("4. Step forward and reverse directions.");
  Serial.println();
}
```

Comment: prints everything in the argument, followed by a newline .... in other words, prints just a newline

Comment: when you post  code in a question, select all of the code and press `ctrl-k` or click the `{}` button .... all of the code will be indented by 4 spaces, which causes  it to be displayed as code ...... upvote for being concerned with code formatting

Comment: That's simple. Thanks! So if you had printed text (surrounded by quotation marks) before, the same effect would be achieved by putting in a "\n", correct?

Comment: yes, `serial.print("\n");` gives same result as `serial.println();`

Comment: @jsotola: No, `Serial.println()` outputs a `'\r'` before the `'\n'`, which `Serial.print("\n")` doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

It simply prints a newline to the serial monitor. Just for spacing.

Answer (score 2):

To complement jose can u c's answer: the Arduino Serial object uses
CRLF as the end-of-line marker. That's an ASCII CR (carriage return,
or `'\r'` in C) followed by ASCII LF (line feed, `'\n'` in C). Thus,

```c++
Serial.println();
```

is equivalent to

```c++
Serial.print("\r\n");
```

Comment: This is a cool expansion on some fundamental formatting stuff. Thank you for the info